# CMake command-line help for user options

Tags: cmake

I have some options in my CMakeLists.txt file that can be selected with `-D` on the command line, like this:

```
# Set some options the user may choose
OPTION(USE_MPI "Use the MPI library for parallelization" OFF)
OPTION(USE_OPENMP "Use OpenMP for parallelization" OFF)
OPTION(TESTING "Enable testing of both Fortran and Python code" OFF)
OPTION(PYTHON_TOOLS "Build the python helper tools" OFF)
OPTION(BUILD_DOCS "Build the documentation; turns on PYTHON_TOOLS" OFF)
```

and I can activate one of them with something like

```
$ cmake . -DUSE_MPI=ON
```

Sometimes I forget what the options I have chosen are.  It would be nice if there was some sort of `-h` flag I could use to display those on the command line in an automated way (in the style of python's `argparse`).

Is there an automated way to generate help documentation for a particular CMakeLists.txt, and/or call that help with some sort of `-h` or `--help` flag?  I'm looking for something that will give me this behavior:

```
$ cmake . --help
USE_MPI - Use the MPI library for parallelization (Default: OFF)
USE_OPENMP - Use OpenMP for parallelization (Default: OFF)
TESTING - Enable testing of both Fortran and Python code (Default: OFF)
PYTHON_TOOLS - Build the python helper tools (Default: OFF)
BUILD_DOCS - Build the documentation; turns on PYTHON_TOOLS (Default: OFF)
```

If there is no automated way, is there at least an easy way to pass `--help` or `-h` to CMakeLists.txt so that I can manually write a help message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the closest to what you're looking for is the [`-L`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#opt%3a-LAH) command line arg.  Running `cmake . -LH` should configure your project, then output all your cached, non-advanced variables along with their help strings.

The [`i`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#opt%3a-i) arg also allows you to see the current values of `option`s, but this actually runs cmake in command line "wizard mode" - it configures the project, asking you to set/update each variable one at a time.

Comment: Oooh, that's neat!  When I do that, it also outputs some variables set by other things (such as CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET).  Do you know if it is possible to filter out only the ones I set?

Comment: @SethMMorton - No, I don't know of any way to do that - sorry!  Maybe a reasonable workaround is to have a naming convention for all your own options so that they all have a common prefix.  That way, at least they'll be grouped together in the `-L` output.

Comment: Yes, one great idea after another!